# Is there a fast implementation of RSA for Microcontrollers?

Tags: rsa, implementation, embedded

Zhe Liu, Johann Großschädl, and Ilya Kizhvatov. ["Efficient and Side-Channel Resistant RSA Implementation for 8-bit AVR Microcontrollers"](http://www.caad.arch.ethz.ch/noolab/files/external/conferences/IoT2010_proceedings/pdf/WS1/WS1_6.%20seciot2010_submission_12_final_v0.pdf) describes a fast implementation, but only contains a sketch of the algorithm with partial pseudo-code.

Is there a worked implementation publicly available?
If not, what is a good fast implementation for small-memory footprint microcontrollers?

Comment: The paper's claim is $76⋅10^6$ CPU cycles for 1024-bit private key operation (+12% for side-channel protection), with like $\mathcal O(n^3)$ scaling. This is impressive, but still credible: about 8 cycles for one 8×8→16 bit MUL and two 8-bit ADD, which leave about 4 cycles for operand fetches and overhead, using a method that plausibly minimizes fetches and overhead by leveraging the numerous CPU registers. However, in practical terms in the Smart Card industry that still is _too slow, not security certified_. We do private-key RSA with special hardware; software is good only for public-key.